# <search.h> header file not available

Tags: c

I can't find the search.h header file mentioned in spell.c, and hence the compiler can't find `hcreate()`, `hsearch()` and `ENTRY`.

Ref:

- http://marcelotoledo.com/how-to-write-a-spelling-corrector/
- https://github.com/marcelotoledo/spelling_corrector/blob/master/spell.c

Comment: It seems that these non standard functions are not available on your platform (which BTW is?).

Comment: It is MSys2 on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<search.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/search.h.html) header is a POSIX-standard header — and the library functions it declares include:

- hash search ([`hsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hsearch.html))
- linear search ([`lsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lsearch.html))
- tree search ([`tsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tsearch.html))

Those pages each list the set of relevant functions for a particular search.  Note that binary search, aka [`bsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bsearch.html), is defined by the C standard rather than POSIX.

The functions were part of Unix SVR4 (and possibly other System V versions), and made it into the Single Unix Specification and hence POSIX too.

If your system doesn't support the header, then it isn't strictly POSIX compliant.  You can certainly find implementations of the functions on the web (BSD, Linux — and probably other places too).  You may be able to find a version to download for your system.  (Macs have it already; I'd expect to find AIX, HP-UX, Solaris include it by default, too.)

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed an issue with Mingw / Msys2. It works on a standard Linux machine.

Comment: By the way, any idea how to add this to Mingw/Msys2 system?\

Comment: I’ve not played with MinGW. I tend to use Cygwin instead, but that’s because I’m not developing Windows apps. So I can’t help much.  Sorry.